# Click function for an add/remove button in JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am currently trying to get an add/remove button to move one item from a table to another table. Once something is checked and the corresponding button is clicked, it should move the checked item from that table to the opposite while removing it from the current table.  With the code I currently have the buttons do nothing at all. I added both my html and js code. I am new to stack so hopefully this is formatted correctly.

```
----Javascript File----    

//Gives table striped look
function stripeTable() {
    var rows = $('tr');
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var jqRow = $(rows[i]);
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            jqRow.addClass('row1');
        } else {
            jqRow.addClass('row2');
        }
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    //List of dictionaries of offered courses
    var courses = [
        {"class":"CMSC 321","time": "10:30AM-11:20AM ", "days":"MWF"},
        {"class":"CMSC 181","time": "10:50AM-11:40AM ", "days":"TTR"},
        {"class":"CMSC 284","time": "2:00PM-3:15PM ", "days":"T"},
        {"class":"BUSN 100","time": "11:30AM-12:45PM ", "days":"TTR"},
        {"class":"CRIM 295","time": "11:30AM-12:45PM ", "days":"MWF"},
        {"class":"ENGL 100","time": "8:30AM-9:20AM ", "days":"MWF"},
        {"class":"MATH 190","time": "10:30AM-11:45AM ", "days":"TR"},
        {"class":"MUSC 115","time": "1:30PM-2:45PM ", "days":"TTR"},
    
    ];

    makeCourses();

    //makes the offered courses table
    function makeCourses(){
        var tbody = $('#courses tbody'),
        props = ["class", "time", "days"];
        $.each(courses, function(i, course) {
            var tr = $('<tr> ');
            $.each(props, function(i, prop) {
                $('<td> ').html(course[prop]).appendTo(tr);  
            });
            $('<td><input type="checkbox" class="add">').appendTo(tr);
            tbody.append(tr);
        });
    };

    //disables button if needed
    $('.add').click(function(){
        $('.AddB').prop('disabled', !$('.add:checked').length);
    });

    //moves list items to course scheduler
    $('.AddB').click(function(){
        $('.add:checked').appendTo('current');
        $('.add:checked').remove('current');
        makeCourses();
        makeCurrent();
    });

    //list of dictionaries of current schedule
    var current = [
        {"class":"MATH 371","time": "10:30AM-11:45AM ", "days":"TR"},
        {"class":"CMSC 285","time": "9:20AM-10:10AM ", "days":"MWF"},
        {"class":"CMSC 284","time": "2:00PM-3:15PM ", "days":"T"},

    ];

    makeCurrent();

    //makes the current schedule table
    function makeCurrent(){ 
        var tbody = $('#current tbody'),
        props = ["class", "time", "days"];
        $.each(current, function(i, currentcourse) {
            var tr = $('<tr> ');
            $.each(props, function(i, prop) {
                $('<td> ').html(currentcourse[prop]).appendTo(tr);  
            });
            $('<td><input type="checkbox" class="remove">').appendTo(tr);
            tbody.append(tr);

        });
   };

    //disables button if needed
    $('.remove').click(function(){
        $('.removeB').prop('disabled', !$('.remove:checked').length);
    });

    //moves list items to course scheduler
    $('.removeB').click(function(){
        $('.remove:checked').appendTo('courses');
        $('.remove:checked').remove('courses');
        makeCurrent();
        makeCourses();
    });

    //Make home page table
    var tbody = $('#currentH tbody'),
    props = ["class", "time", "days"];
    $.each(current, function(i, currentcourse) {
        var tr = $('<tr> ');
        $.each(props, function(i, prop) {
            $('<td> ').html(currentcourse[prop]).appendTo(tr);  
        });
        $('<td>').appendTo(tr);
        tbody.append(tr);
    });
 
    stripeTable();


});

----HTML File----

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--Source for CSS-->
    <title>Course Scheduler: Edit</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scheduler.css">

  </head>

  <body>

<!--Navbar-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Course Schedule</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="home.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="edit.html">Edit <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
  
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>

<!--Intro to page-->
<center>
    <div id="main-content">
 
      <h3>Welcome to the Edit Page. This is where you add and remove classes. </h3>

  <!--The current courses taking table-->
  <form>
       <table id="current">
        <caption class="currentTitle">Current Schedule <button type="button" 
class='removeB'disabled>Remove</button></caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Course</th><th>Time</th><th>Days</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
  </table>
</form>

  <!--The courses offered table-->
  <form>
        <table id="courses">
          <caption class="courseTitle">Courses <button type="button" 
class='AddB'disabled>Add</button> </caption>
          <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Course</th><th>Time</th><th>Days</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody >
          </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>    

    </div>
  </center>

<!--Source files for jquery and javascript-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js">
  </script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="edit.js">
  </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Call the  `make...()` functions before creating the listener. The elements currently don't exist when you try to look for them. Or - Use [Event Delgation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: I might have misread it a bit since makeCurrent() shows up several times. Either way if you do `$('#current').on('click', '.add', function(){...` should work fine for all the circumstances

Comment: I called the create functions before creating the listener and now when clicking the add/remove button it just adds all elements of the table to itself for both tables no matter what button i click.

Comment: OK. Take a look at what I did with the "removeB" listener https://jsfiddle.net/L0onsjbr/ . Also used bootstrap classes for the striping and removed the `stripeTable()`. I didn't do anything with the Add button yet

Comment: Thank you charlieftl, it helped a lot everything is mostly working. Thanks for including the bootstrap comment too. The only issue i have left is when something is added to the opposite table the checkbox no longer works. It is also not updating the home table but i did not include that file. It is essentially the same code for the home table but without checkboxes.